# how to make jackson use only private (non-static) fields while serializing/deserializing

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I want to configure jackson so that it uses only the private non-static fields (and only their corresponding getters/setters) while serializing and deserializing java objects. Is that possible?
certain getters might not correspond to a field, I want to prevent their invocation as well while serializing.

**NOTE**: I can't use annotation based configuration (@JsonProperty) as my java classes are generated at build time.

Comment: Simply be explicit. Use `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonIgnore` as appropriate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can't do that. my java classes are generated at build time